# how to remove the browser history after clicking logout button in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i php code which contains user login .if user logs in he can move to next page . on logout he can able to move to the index.php (which contains login.php).
after logout the page should not move to previous page on click backbutton.
how to create it ?

this is my logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
session_unset();  
    header("location:index.php");

?>
```

and my index.php page has

```
<html><head><script>$(document).ready(function(){
$("#check_user").click(function() {

        var userType=$("#userType").val();
        var userEmail = $("#log_user_email").val();
        var password = $("#log_password").val();
        if (userEmail=="" || password=="" || userType=="select"){
        alert("empty fields !!!");
        }
        else{
        var dataString = 'userEmail='+ userEmail + '&password=' + password +'&userType='+userType;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "check.php",
          data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            if(data == "failure"){
                alert("user name or password not valid.");
                return false;
            }
            if(data == "success"){
                alert("successfuly logged in.");
                window.location='login.php';
                //location.reload();
            }
            if(data == "already logged in"){
            alert("already logged in");
                location.reload();
            }
          }
         });
    }
});

});
   function logout()
   {
   window.location='logout.php';
   }</script></head>
<body><label name="email"  >Email</label>
         <input type="email" id="log_user_email" placeholder="example@example.com" />
         <label name="password">Password</label>
         <input type="password" id="log_password" placeholder="*********"/>
         <input type="button" value="Login" id="check_user" onclick="check()" style="cursor:pointer;" />
         <input type="button" value="logout" onclick="logout();"></body></html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a good approach. you need to check the user is logged on in your pages rather then try to disable the back button. Otherwise people will just change the url and bypass the need to login

Answer (score 1):

A best way to do would be...

add in the pages you must be logged in to navigate:

```
  <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
<!-- your HTML code -->
<? } else echo "you must log in!"; ?>
```

Or something similar

Comment: but it is taking to "the you must log in!"; page first

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a number of ways to try to disable the backbutton, but actually you have no guarantees that any of them will work: http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm

You can't stop the backbutton, but you can try to make it harder to use it.